# How to do setup Azure AD B2C login fro mobile - Android - like Login/Signup/forgot password

Tags: android, azure, azure-active-directory

I've never worked with Azure.
I was suggested to use Azure AD to do the login authentication. I tried to use a couple app provided in the Documentation but they are 3 years old and are not properly working. Also one of the app log was saying that cannot be used for B2C base don the keys i provided and the other one is not even compiling

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal - runs but not able to make the "Call API" button to work

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-appauth - not compiling

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the document it will help you in achieving Azure AD B2C Sign-in using an [Android application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/signin-appauth-android?tabs=app-reg-ga).

Refer to [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/tree/master/apps/mobile-react-native-ios-android-appauth) to set up your IOS and Android environment

There are some code sample you go through the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples#mobile-and-desktop-apps).

If you face any issue in the development process you can raise the SO question with your error details.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_cTGYjbZJtEJ2Ojj&Q_CHL=gl
>

Comment: The sample uses AppAuth and the documentation states: "Microsoft does not provide fixes for 3rd party libraries and has not done a review of those libraries. This sample is using a 3rd party library called AppAuth that has been tested for compatibility in basic scenarios with the Azure AD B2C." Is there any way to use Azure AD B2C directly?

Comment: Azure AD B2C for Andriod samples are developed with the 3rd party library AppAuth. You can use these samples as these are developed by the microsoft team but the support and fixes the samples are directly not taken care by the microsoft, we need to raise the issues through the GitHub where respective sample owners will handle the support/issues.